# Update Table value from other table using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have two tables Product_Staging and Product. The contents of the table are below.

Product_Staging:

```
Account_No         Product_No        Cur_Revenue             Prev_Revenue
12                 AB                5.0                     3.0
13                 BC                4.0                     4.0
15                 DF                10.0                    7.5
17                 BC                NULL                    NULL
18                 AZ                NULL                    NULL
```

Product:

```
Account_No         Product_No        Cur_Revenue             Prev_Revenue
12                 AB                1.0                     3.0
13                 BC                4.0                     5.0
16                 DF                10.0                    17.5
17                 CG                5.0                     6.0
18                 AZ                NULL                    NULL
```

I need to update the Product table's Cur_Revenue and Prev_Revenue fields based on the following conditions.

1. When there is a match between Account_No and Product_No in both tables and the revenue values are different, the Cur_Revenue and Prev_Revenue from Product_Staging should be updated in Product table.
2. When a record exists in Product for a certain combination of Account_No and Product_No and if it does not exists in Product_Staging table, the Cur_Revenue and Prev_Revenue from Product should be set to NULL.
3. When there is match between Account_No and Product_No in both tables and the revenue values are same, the Product table should NOT be updated.
4. When a record exists in Product for a particular Account_No and Product_No with revenue values as NULL and if there is no record exists in Product_Staging for the Account_No and Product_No combination, the Product record should NOT be updated.

Product After Update:

```
Account_No         Product_No        Cur_Revenue             Prev_Revenue
12                 AB                5.0                     3.0 (Updated from Product_Staging)
13                 BC                4.0                     4.0 (Updated from Product_Staging)
16                 DF                                            (Cleared)
17                 CG                NULL                   NULL                            (Cleared)
18                 AZ                NULL                   NULL (Not Updated)
```

The below query is working to achieve the results of #1 and #2, but not for #3 and #4 and this is where I am struggling.

```
update p SET
p.Cur_Revenue =  ps.Cur_Revenue,
p.Prev_Revenue = ps.Prev_Revenue
from Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_Staging ps on
    p.Account_No= ps.Account_No AND p.Product_No = ps.Product_No
```

This query is updating Product even when the revenue values are same in Product and Product_Staging table for a certain Account_No and Product_No combination. Also, I am not sure how to skip the records from getting updated in Product when the revenue values are NULL and there is no record in Product_Staging table.

Comment: You should probably include the things you've attempted to make this work so that it doesn't look like a homework question.

Comment: Also, think through your requirements. What should you do if Table A has a row with non-null values in the fields to be updated into Table B, but Table B does not have a row matching Table A? If Table A has a NULL in the updating fields, but Table B has a row, what should happen?  TL;DR - be certain that you know what to do if you get an unexpected but predictable condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You APPEAR to be pretty close, but the conditions need to be put in your SET component.  The LEFT-JOIN is ok, just what are you updating based on.

```
update p SET
      p.Cur_Revenue = ps.Cur_Revenue,
      p.Prev_Revenue = ps.Prev_Revenue
   from 
      Product p
         LEFT JOIN Product_Staging ps 
            on p.Account_No = ps.Account_No 
           AND p.Product_No = ps.Product_No
   where
          -- This is for condition #3
          (     NOT ps.Product_No IS NULL
           AND (    p.Cur_Revenue <> ps.Cur_Revenue
                 OR p.Prev_Revenue <> ps.Prev_Revenue ))
     OR   -- This is for condition #4
          (     ps.Product_No IS NULL
           AND p.Cur_Revenue IS NULL
           AND p.Prev_Revenue IS NULL )
```

There are only 2 conditions that your Product table should be updated per your example.

1 - Match in BOTH tables and revenues are different, update with values from staging.

2 - When NO matching record in staging, set production to NULL.

```
update p SET
      p.Cur_Revenue = ps.Cur_Revenue,
      p.Prev_Revenue = ps.Prev_Revenue
   from 
      Product p
         LEFT JOIN Product_Staging ps 
            on p.Account_No = ps.Account_No 
           AND p.Product_No = ps.Product_No
```

You have a left-join to the staging on the matching Product and Account.  So worst case scenario you either have a match or you don't.  If you do NOT have a match, then all values in the staging table are NULL.  If there IS a match, you want to update whatever its staging value is.  So the SET is directly to that column.  Per #1, if a match, update (you have a value, good).  Per #2, if NO match, set to null (no match, the values are null).  So we don't even NEED the case/when condition.

Let's clarify your conditions 3 & 4 to NOT update where not necessary. First, #3, there IS a match and revenues are the same.

3. When there is match between Account_No and Product_No in both tables and the revenue values are same, the Product table should NOT be updated.  Notice the entire portion is wrapped in parentheses.  the `NOT ps.Product_No IS NULL` means it DID find a match to the staging table.  When that is the case, we only want to update when EITHER of the revenues are not the same.  So this is ANDed with a parentheses on either 1 OR the other revenue is not the same (hence <> ).  So, if we have a matching record and ONE (or both) of the amounts are different, we must update it.

   (      NOT ps.Product_No IS NULL
   AND (   p.Cur_Revenue <> ps.Cur_Revenue
   OR p.Prev_Revenue <> ps.Prev_Revenue ))
4. When a record exists in Product for a particular Account_No and Product_No with revenue values as NULL and if there is no record exists in Product_Staging for the Account_No and Product_No combination, the Product record should NOT be updated.

Here, first hit is NO match in staging, hence `ps.Product_No IS NULL`, but also, if no match in staging, BOTH of the revenue fields must also be null to not require the update.  So I am ANDing both of those revenues to null.  If either one or both have a value, you want to change them TO null per your #2 condition to update.

```
OR (     ps.Product_No IS NULL
     AND p.Cur_Revenue IS NULL
     AND p.Prev_Revenue IS NULL )
```

Comment: thanks for your response. However, my requirement is not to re-update the record if the old and new values are same. Relaxing this criteria might include several million duplicate updates to the table.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli, see revision WHERE clause to prevent unnecessary updates.

Comment: Thanks, it was way over my head. I have to sit for couple of minutes to digest it and then try it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli, I did one final revision with final query complete and complete explanation on each part to help you follow along.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. It really helps. If I am understanding it right, for the #3 condition, I can check for ps.Account_No also, correct? i.e., "NOT ( ps.Account_No IS NULL" as the match is with both Account_No and Product_No.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli, you can actually check for ANY column in the table to be NULL, I just happened to pick one of them

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question again, I think you need to move one join condition to a `case` for the update. I'm still confused about #2 though and where `Product2` is.

```
update p SET
    p.Cur_Revenue = case 
                        when p.Product_No = ps.Product_No and p.Cur_Revenue != p.Prev_Revenue then ps.Cur_Revenue       --1
                        when ps.Account_No is null or ps.Product_No != p.Product_No then NULL                           --2
                        when p.Product_No = ps.Product_No and p.Cur_Revenue = p.Prev_Revenue then p.Cur_Revenue         --3
                        when p.Product_No != ps.Product_No then p.Cur_Revenue                                           --4
                        else p.Cur_Revenue                                                                              --catch all
                    end
    ,p.Prev_Revenue =case 
                        when p.Product_No = ps.Product_No and p.Cur_Revenue != p.Prev_Revenue then ps.Prev_Revenue      --1
                        when ps.Account_No is null or ps.Product_No != p.Product_No then NULL                           --2
                        when p.Product_No = ps.Product_No and p.Cur_Revenue = p.Prev_Revenue then p.Prev_Revenue        --3
                        when p.Product_No != ps.Product_No then p.Prev_Revenue                                          --4
                        else p.Prev_Revenue                                                                         --catch all
                    end
from Product p
INNER JOIN Product_Staging ps on
    p.Account_No= ps.Account_No
```